# Pass value in textarea in view phtml page when textarea created in zf2 form attributes

Tags: zend-framework2, textarea, zend-form

I want to create text area with the help of zf2 form attributes and pass value in text area in view page so how to do this? So I want something like:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="title">
    <?php echo $x;?>
</textarea>
```

Now I want to change this to zf2 form and pass `$x` in view html page.

Comment: <textarea class="form-control" name="title"><?php echo $x;?></textarea> and i want to change with zf2 form and pass $x in view html page.

Comment: you should edit your question and not post a comment if you want to add information. I updated your question with the information from the comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you wanted to set value for textarea INSIDE the view template.

```
$form->prepare();
/../
$element = $form->get('input_name');
$element->setValue($x);
/../
echo $this->formInput($element);
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('input_name'));
```

So it is possible to set input's value the way described above.

It would be worth if you post some code examples, in the future.